# Can you turn off Visual Studio 2008 Query formatting?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008

Is it possible to turn off the query re-formatting that happens when you edit a query for a database in Visual Studio? (i.e. r-click a data source and select New Query)

This is happening when we are writing sql queries against a sql compact 3.5 database.

Its rather irritating when your carefully indented and formatted query is munged into visual studio's formatting (which is illegible!). I cannot find any setting in the options dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this one off, as far as I can tell, there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Add New "Sql Script" instead of the Query to prevent re-formating but still keep the syntax highlighting.

Comment: As far as I can work out, thats just for sql server - you cannot do it with sql compact... (and i'd open it in management studio, but it doesn't support sql compact 3.5)